# Unable to install Photoshop CS6 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wine, photoshop

I have a problem installing Photoshop CS6 using Wine (staging ideally nor version with similar compatibility).

#### Tried solution

1. Installation failed - https://pastebin.com/FkYhRvZX

   - Attempt: installing, winehq-devel, winehq-stable, winehq-staging, wine-stable, wine-stable-amd64, wine-staging, wine64, wine1.6
   - Outcome: no effect, but staging version is able to run Witcher 3.
2. Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

   - Attempt: `sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module*`
   - Outcome: no effect on staging, other versions seems not affected by this error.
3. Install Photoshop CS6 using playonlinux
    This solved the issue, special thanks to @N0rbert.

#### Expected

Install and run Photoshop CS6 on Ubuntu 18.04.

#### Disclaimer

I found many articles about this issue, but all of them seem outdated, none are working on this issue, and the error message isn't helpful.

Comment: It's not an answer, but I develop [Photopea.com](https://www.Photopea.com) and many people use it as a PS replacement on Linux :)  
It handles modern PSD files much better than PS CS6.

Comment: @Ivan Kuckir Personally big fan of Photopea keep up the good work! (☞ﾟヮﾟ)☞ i would prefer Photopea over Photoshop i'm professional graphic designer and it just keep crashing and bugs out on every platform, but unfortunately i need it for logo development (i use rastr with optimized alpha channel which is then converted into vector) and i'm reliable on shortcuts so it's not ideal for me to use. The alternative is gimp which would need hard modifications to make it work for my workload..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try to install it with PlayOnLinux. It seems to be supported by [PlayOnLinux team](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-2316-Adobe_Photoshop_CS6.html).
It will install the corresponding (and tested) version of Wine which can launch Photoshop.

1. Install PlayOnLinux with

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install playonlinux
   ```
2. Run PlayOnLinux (from Games category or from terminal with `playonlinux`) and click *Install* then click on *Graphics* and select *Adobe Photoshop CS6*,

   [image: Adobe Photoshop CS6 in PlayOnLinux]

   click *Install* and follow instructions in the wizard.
3. After installation desktop-launcher will be created.

Comment: I tried this and it sort of worked. The shell gui of playonlinux seemed to install, but there were no applications in it! It was empty. Now I'm getting this #ERROR: `Redirecting output to ‘wget-log.1’.
[POL_Config_Write] Message: Config write: LAST_TIMESTAMP 1581189447`. Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

PlayOnLinux version 4.3.4
For Bionic Version Ubuntu:

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_bionic.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

PlayOnLinux version 4.3.4
For Xenial Version

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_xenial.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

After installing playonLinux go to 'Install a program' then type the program you want to install and proceed.

Thank you!