# Photoshop fails to install due to PlayonLinux issue

Tags: wine, playonlinux, photoshop

I am trying to install Photoshop CS6 on my Ubuntu machine (dual-boot) with Windows OS.

Before proceeding with the steps, I researched here and found this link: [Installing Photoshop on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045855/unable-to-install-photoshop-cs6-on-ubuntu-18-04)

I followed the steps listed in the answer, but my PlayOnLinux failed and gave me this error:

[image: PlayOnLinux Error while installing Photoshop CS6]

The installation was working fine, and even the missing Microsoft Fonts got installed automatically. But, this unexpected error aborted the installation completely.

**Note:** Before installing Photoshop CS6, I installed **MS PAINT** through Wine, and it got installed without any errors.

Also, note that when I visit Home >> PlayOnLinux's Virtual Drives folder, I can see the virtual drive created for Adobe Photoshop CS6. Here's the proof:

[image: POL-Virtual-Drives]

Comment: Have you tried starting it? I have seen this error a lot of times, but in most cases the application worked despite the error.

Comment: I did, but I did not find it anywhere. I read on a thread that - even if I encounter such an error, I must wait for 5 minutes and then check. Instead of 5, I waited for 20minutes, but still, nothing changed. 

I searched for Adobe Photoshop in every possible location, but alas, failed.

Comment: I don't see how waiting would help, but you can look in the Photoshop CS6 folder in your screenshot. There is probably a folder called drive_c, which contains the windows file system. I don't know where Photoshop installs, but probably Program Files. See if you can find the appropriate exe file there. In PlayOnLinux, you can "run a .exe in this virtual drive" and select it manually. Alternatively, you can "create a shortcut" from that drive in which case POL will look for .exe files for you.

Comment: I can definitely find drive_c folder having Windows files, but there is no .exe file. 
I checked every folder two times. 

As far as waiting time is concerned, even I agree it doesn't make sense, but as it was written there, so I thought of giving it a try.

Comment: At which step did the installation crash? I just tried it, the install script seems to be buggy. Adobe AIR is downloaded but the installer doesn't find it. Additionally, the .exe installer I found on Adobe's website was a self extracting archive, so I had to start the installer itself after extracting the archive using the "run a .exe in this virtual drive" functionality of POL. Since all prerequisites have been installed successfully, try to manually install it in the same virtual drive. I didn't get past the "register now" step in the installer so I couldn't test it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. In my case also, I was done with Adobe Air downloading and missing MS Fonts download, and then I encountered this error suddenly. Can you explain the "Run a .exe in this Virtual Drive" functionality of the POL again and what steps do I need to take to install it manually??

Comment: Looking at the [install script](https://www.playonlinux.com/de/app-2316-Adobe_Photoshop_CS6.html), the only missing steps are installing AIR and Photoshop itself. The AIR installer should be located at `~/.PlayOnLinux/tmp/`. In POL, click "Configure". In the newly opened window, select the _PhotoshopCS6_ drive and in the "Miscellaneous" tab, click "Run a .exe file in this virtual drive" and select the .exe file you want to run, i.e. the setup file.

Comment: Opening `~/.PlayOnLinux/tmp/` shows me two files: `check_dd_amd64` and, check_dd_x86'. 
Also, when I open POL, and follow up with your steps, it asks me to browse to the location of the '.exe' file. Now where exactly should I find this .exe file??

Comment: That's at least the location where it should have been downloaded. Anyway, I'm not sure if AIR is needed at all. The .exe file is the setup file that you would normally run to install Photoshop in Windows. Depending on how/where you bought it, you may have it on CD-ROM or you can download it from Adobe's website. It's actually called `Set-up.exe` in the case of Photoshop CS6.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91430/discussion-between-manu-mathur-and-danzel).